# SCDF - How to configure a remote maven repo on Kubernetes Deployment

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I am using SCDF deployment on k8s and trying to add a new Task Application from our internal Maven repo. By default, SCDF seems to only lookup in the [springRepo] repository. I followed the documentation to add a new maven repo [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-maven) .

Since the documentation only talks about CloudFoundry example, I added these lines to application.yaml section based on my understanding.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    dataflow:
      task:
        platform:
          local:
            accounts:
              localDev:
             ********
  datasource:
        uri:  xxx
        *********
  maven:
    remote-repositories:
      repo1:
        url: https://repo1
        auth:
          username: user1
          password: pass1
        snapshot-policy:
          update-policy: daily
          checksum-policy: warn
        release-policy:
          update-policy: never
          checksum-policy: fail
```

While adding the app I used the syntax : maven://:[:[:]]:. However, when I launch the task, it fails with error : Failed to resolve maven Resource XXX at configured Remote Repository : [springRepo]

How can I override it to search in my newly added repo.. why SCDF still only searching in default [springRepo]? Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

The property prefix is `maven.remote-repositories` but what you have is `spring.maven.remote-repositories`.

You need to specify:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    dataflow:
      task:
        platform:
          local:
            accounts:
              localDev:
             ********
  datasource:
        uri:  xxx
        *********
maven:
  remote-repositories:
    repo1:
      url: https://repo1
      ...
```

Please note that the Kubernetes deployment works with containers rather than maven jar artifacts and hence, you need to have your apps registered with the app's URI using `docker:` prefix.

Comment: Thanks Gopinathan. looks like adding maven at the same level a spring worked fine. It is now looking into repo1 also. However, its still not finding my image. Could be something wrong with my maven: url. Will figure it out. Thanks for your clarification on docker: images. That's what I am using right now. Wanted to try a maven jar file instead. I was thinking , SCDF will add some kind of magic wrapper on my jar to run n SCDF :).